# ¿Cómo puedo verificar la existencia de varios archivos en Bash?

Tags: bash, condiciones

Intento verificar que dos archivos existen pero me salta esto:

> bash: [: too many arguments

O con localización en castellano:

> bash: [: demasiados argumentos

¿Qué puse mal?

```
if [ -f test.txt $$ -f test2.txt ]
then
   echo "si"
else
   echo "no"
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que usar doble `&` para indicar "Y". Por tanto, la forma correcta sería:

```
if [ -f test.txt ] && [ -f test2.txt ]; then
    echo "si"
else
    echo "no"
fi
```

Comment: Disculpa, em ese caso es &&, lo corrijo

Answer (score 6):

Estás cometiendo dos errores en tu script:

- El operador lógico "Y" es `&&` y no `$$`. La variable `$` (se accede a ella mediante `$$`) indica el `pid` de la shell en curso.
- Cada función de comprobación debe estar encerrada en sus propios corchetes `[ -f ... ]` y sólo puede contener una única comprobación (en tu caso `-f` y, además, `-f` sólo permite un parámetro adicional con el nombre del archivo).

Tu comprobación se expandiría a lo siguiente (asumiendo un `pid` de la shell de `4354`):

```
if [ -f test.txt 4354 -f test2.txt ]
```

Como la comprobación `-f` sólo permite un parámetro (el nombre del archivo) los parámetros `4354`, `-f` y `test2.txt` sobran. De ahí el mensaje ***too many arguments*** (*demasiados argumentos*).

Éste sería un ejemplo de uso correcto:

```
if [ -f test.txt ] && [ -f test2.txt ]
then
  echo "si"
else
  echo "no"
fi
```

Comment: ahi esta gracias y tambien me falto un ; al final gracias otra vez

Comment: No es necesario agregar un `;` al final, sólo se debe agregar cuando pones `then` en la misma línea que el `if`.

Comment: Por cierto, acabas de poner como correcta la otra respuesta, no la mía xD